# Cannot save canvas with draggable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to save my HTML canvas to file which I can successfully do, but it's not saving any objects I've dragged into the canvas.

So, by using the Draggable JQuery I can happily move my object around screen and place it ontop of my canvas. When I save the canvas using the `Canvas.ToDataURL()` it does not save my dragged objects (and also does something strange to my canvas in the jsFiddle, it appears to change the colour of my canvas?).

To see a "working" example, please visit my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JVSFS/74/

Please simply drag the green box over the blue box and click the save button. The result will be shown underneath (just an orange box).

HTML

```
    <canvas id="MyCanvas" class="canvas"></canvas>

    <div class="popup_click">
        <div id="popup_title">Drag</div>
    </div>

    <asp:HiddenField ID="hideMe" runat="server" />

    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="ClickMe" Text="Click" OnClientClick="SaveMe()" />

<button onclick="SaveMe()">Try it</button>

<p>Results: </p>
<img id="myImage" />
```

JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.popup_click').show(0).draggable();
    });

    function SaveMe() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillStyle = "orange";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        document.getElementById("myImage").src = image;


        document.getElementById("hideMe").value = image;
    }
```

CSS

```
.popup_click {
            background: #80FF80;
            width: 50px;        }

        .canvas {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #0FC;
}
```

How can I get the dragged object to save? I assume I have to tell the Canvas that the object is part of it's context but no idea how and my own searches came up with nothing.

Comment: have a div over the canvas, does not means got it inside the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

> You can't just draw HTML into a canvas. Instead, you need to use an SVG image containing the content you want to render. To draw HTML content, you'd use a  element containing the HTML, then draw that SVG image into your canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
               "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px'>" +
                 "<em>I</em> like <span style='color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;'>cheese</span>" +
               "</div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
img.src = url;
```

Comment: This is interesting but, I'm afraid I don't see how this can help when there are draggable items on screen.

Comment: It's an operation that you should do manually (listen to drop, calculate the offset of the div, create svg and draw it inside the canvas)... it's annoying but possible

Comment: hmmmm... some what more complicated than I was hoping but fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your draggable object isn't in the canves.
They are simple html elements.
It'll save only the objects whose created with canvas methods.

Any way `to create html elements on canvas you have to use svg`.
Mozilla show nice way to to this but you need to get all the css to inline css before.
[mozilla explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

**Anyway with using svg on you canvas you won't be able to use `toDataUrl` because of security policy.**

Comment: I'm not able to add anything to my canvas. For example, if I do `<canvas>html code</canvas>` then the canvas does not show at all!

Comment: If you specify innerText to the canvas it'll be displayed only form browsers that not compatible with canvas element.
Like old explorer.
For drawing into canvas you have to use only scripts.
You have methods for text creating. just look at the api.